# "Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class" exception when starting a project in Netbeans 7.2

Tags: netbeans-7

I've just installed the newest version of Netbeans ( 7.2 ) and tried to run an existing Swing project in it. I got the following exception:

StackTrace:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file com/eositservices/eldorado/dialogs/zahlungverrechnung/model/InitDataList
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2427)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:1935)
    at java.awt.Component.isCoalesceEventsOverriden(Component.java:5975)
    at java.awt.Component.access$500(Component.java:169)
    at java.awt.Component$3.run(Component.java:5929)
    at java.awt.Component$3.run(Component.java:5927)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Component.checkCoalescing(Component.java:5926)
    at java.awt.Component.<init>(Component.java:5895)
    at java.awt.Container.<init>(Container.java:249)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.<init>(JComponent.java:570)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:65)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:92)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:100)
    at com.eositservices.eldorado.masken.FormForderung.<init>(FormForderung.java:72)
    at com.eositservices.eldorado.tabsheets.zahlung.TSZahlung.<init>(TSZahlung.java:183)
    at com.eositservices.eldorado.masken.TFormForderung.addTabs(TFormForderung.java:366)
    at com.eositservices.eldorado.masken.TFormForderung.initializeComponents(TFormForderung.java:275)
    at com.eositservices.eldorado.masken.TFormForderung.configureComponents(TFormForderung.java:148)
    at com.eositservices.bones.view.components.EOSInternalFrame.setUp(EOSInternalFrame.java:81)
    at com.eositservices.eldorado.masken.TFormForderung.<init>(TFormForderung.java:113)
    at com.eositservices.eldorado.main.MainFrame.oeffneForderung(MainFrame.java:577)
    at com.eositservices.eldorado.main.MainFrame.showForderung(MainFrame.java:488)
    at com.eositservices.eldorado.dev.QuickLogin.openForderung(QuickLogin.java:109)
    at com.eositservices.eldorado.dev.QuickLogin.openInitialViews(QuickLogin.java:143)
    at com.eositservices.eldorado.main.MainFrame$2.run(MainFrame.java:433)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:646)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:607)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:605)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:616)
    at com.eositservices.bones.view.GlobalHotkeyManager.dispatchEvent(GlobalHotkeyManager.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

The method in question looks like this:

```
@Override
public boolean add( InitData e ) {
    boolean returnValue = super.add( e );
     Collections.sort( this, c );
    return returnValue;
}
```

The strange thing is that the exception only comes when I set the project properties to "Compile on save". When the option is unchecked it runs fine. We had no such problems in the previous versions of NetBeans. Is it just a coincidence and I should look elsewhere for the source of this error or has anyone had similar problems? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be a bug in the **NetBeans**.

When this exception occurs, let's make an error in the code (e.g

```
@Override
**efefefefef**
public boolean add( InitData e ) {
    boolean returnValue = super.add( e );
     Collections.sort( this, c );
    return returnValue;
}
```

)

save it and when the Netbeans displays the error, correct it back. I have tried to clear the Project, remove everything from the cache, but nothing happened. But this way helped on me.